# Accidentally turned on Siri using an iPhone 4 (not 4S)

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, voiceover

I was using the Facebook app when it decided to freeze. Out of frustration, I clicked the home button multiple times. I got back to the homescreen with VoiceOver turned on ('Triple-click Home' was not set) and a second later, Siri loaded. I tried to take a screenshot, but Siri closed just before the 'flash' took place.

Has anyone else experienced this? Non-jail broken, iOS 5.0 on Verizon.

---

**Update:**

I have restored my phone a couple of times since this happened, mainly due to this issue: [Audio output and volume controls gone after updating to iOS 5.1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43622/audio-output-and-volume-controls-gone-after-updating-to-ios-5-1)

So, unfortunately, any useful information contained in the crash logs has been lost.

Comment: I have not, but I'd be extremely interested if you can reproduce it

Comment: Yeah, please keep trying to replicate (and film!) this. Would be a fascinating bug with some big ramifications.

Comment: Ditto! I want to know more too!

Answer (score 5):

Was it **Siri** or was it **Voice Control**?  Voice Control has been on iPhone since iOS3.

**Siri** on the left,**Voice Control** on the right.
[image: Siri] [image: Voice Control]

You activate Voice Control by holding the Home button for a few seconds, even while the phone is locked.

Comment: It was not VoiceControl. It was Siri, and it only appeared on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Actualy Voice Control was available on iOS3 when the 3GS was released.

Answer (score 1):

Attach your iPhone to a Mac, If you have access, and see if you can get at the crash logs or the device console. Like others, I'm curious to know more about this. If you can see the crash logs via Xcode or something, you might be able to see more about this. Otherwise, it's a bug which you can't reproduce. Oh well.

Being as siri is part of the OS, it's entirely possible that it loaded, then crashed because of missing files or whatever.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've restored my phone since. I've been dealing with this issue, now: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43622/audio-output-and-volume-controls-gone-after-updating-to-ios-5-1